# Infere the function return type from inside the function

Tags: c++, macros, initialization, type-inference

I have a `class` that, very unfortunately, relies on a two-step initialization. This means that after being constructed, the object is still not ready to be used unless an initialization method has been called:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    bool init();

private:
    bool m_is_initialized;
};
```

Every other method of the class shall follow this policy: if the method is called when the class is not yet initialized, the method should stop executing and log an error on a class specific channel.

Problem is that some methods have a return type. The policy in this case is to return a default constructed value of the return type.

The idea is to have an easy macro that can be called at the beginning of every method implementation, something like:

```
#define CHECK_INITIALIZED                                                  \
if ( !m_is_initialized )                                                   \
{                                                                          \
    LOG_E( m_channel, "%s object not initialized.", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ ); \
    assert( false );                                                       \
    return;                                                                \
}
```

The `return` statement, by the way, is valid only for `void` functions, and does not fit every case. Is there a way to infere the returning type `T` of the function in which the macro is expanded, so that I can return `T()` and make the macro usable everywhere?

EDIT:
Please note that because of a project restriction, exceptions are unfortunately not usable.

Comment: A value-initialized return value is not going to be valid in general. Some types are not default-constructible and others are valid return values. For example, a function could return 0 or "" or whatnot as a successful return value.

Comment: Instead of `return` why not `throw`?

Comment: @chris I know, but as long as the logging happens we are fine with that.

Comment: @NathanOliver the project is restricted on expections topic, we cannot `throw` unfortunately. I will edit my question.

Comment: is this >=c++11 ? if yes, use different macros for the void and non void case, returning "return {};" in the latter ( assuming all such methods returns default constructibles, of course )

Comment: How about `#define CHECK_INITIALIZED(defaultReturnValue)` (where `defaultReturnValue` can be empty) ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes that works fine, unless the return type is a const reference. In that case, a warning is raised by the compiler, which could lead to a runtime crash.

Comment: but note that "unless the return type is a const reference" conflicts with "The policy in this case is to return a default constructed value of the return type" :)

Comment: can you return an optional object rather than an object?

Comment: @RichardHodges we thought about it, but it is a bad idea because will force the caller to handle an error that should not be there in first place. It is a behavior that is not part of any use case, the object should be initialized. But we do not want to crash if it does not. So the idea is to stop executing, log, and return some default.

Comment: I was thinking the same. Perhaps log the error at the point of faulty construction?

Comment: @chris there is a C `assert(false)` after every logging. I will edit my question. That is by the way ignored in release build, and we want it keep it that way and not crash for other reasons, like null pointer etc.

Comment: My bad, I completely skipped that line.

Comment: I'm tempted to add an answer but there are already three answers not answering the question as per the title ( "Is there a way to infere the returning type T of the function in which the macro is expanded, so that I can return T() and make the macro usable everywhere?" ), is this an XY problem ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes probably the question should have been "how to return-interrupt any function, regardless of its returning type".

Answer (score 3):

Why use macros at all? A template will handle this nicely.

```
struct has_init_check
{
protected:
    template<class F>
    auto if_ready(F&& f)
    {
        if (m_is_initialized)
        {
            f();
        }
        else
        {
            // log the error here
        }
    } 

    void notify_initialized()
    {
        m_is_initialized = true;
    }

private:
    bool m_is_initialized = false;
};

class A 
: has_init_check
{
public:
    A();
    bool init() { notify_initialized(); }

    int foo();
    void bar();

};

int A::foo()
{
    int result = 0; // default value
    if_ready([&]
    {
        // logic here
        result = 10;
    });

    return result;    
}

void A::bar()
{
    if_ready([]
    {
        // logic here
    });
}
```

Comment: Macro are being used mainly in order to be able to log the function name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return {};` to express you want a default initialized return type.  This fails though in cases where the type is not default constructable, you are trying to return a reference or the return type is `void`.

Another option would be to use [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)/[`std:optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) as the return type for all of your functions in combination with `return {};`.  This allows you to return a default optional when you do nothing (so the optional is empty).

Another option is to pass a return value to the macro and use that for the return like

```
#define CHECK_INITIALIZED(default_return_value)                            \
if ( !m_is_initialized )                                                   \
{                                                                          \
    LOG_E( m_channel, "%s object not initialized.", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ ); \
    return default_return_value;                                                                \
}
```

Comment: Would return {}; compile if the function "returns" void?

Comment: @roalz, No, but you could have a `std::optional<std::monostate>` or `boost::optional<boost::blank>` to make it uniform.

Comment: Wouldn't it be good/helpful/consistent if c++ would allow "return {};" even for void returning functions?  C++23 anyone? :-)

Comment: @roalz you are being optimistic. I would have said "C++49"

Comment: @roalz, There's a proposal for regular void, but it's really hard to do that without breaking code in any significant way.

Comment: @chris (maybe we are off-topic, sorry) how about allowing both "return;" AND "return {};" for void functions? I.e. for back-compatibility.

Comment: @roalz, We could, but it's one special case of regular void, and it would need to be proven that it has significant benefit.

Comment: @chris Sure, I was just elaborating on possible extensions of Nathan's answer. closed off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer, another approach.

Exceptions are not allowed, but we can still catch initialisation failure at construction time by using a variant(error, object).

We know that all members of our objects will be nothrow_constructible (this is a constraint). They must also therefore be nothrow_moveable.

So we can use a combination of variant and optional to manage object construction and log/halt there on failure.

Now there is no runtime overhead when implementing methods.

```
#include <variant>
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


struct construction_error
{
    construction_error(std::string s)
    : message_(s)
    {}

    const std::string message() const {
        return message_;
    }

    std::string message_;
};

template<class T> using construction_result = std::variant<construction_error, T>;

template<class T> struct tag {};

template<class T, class...Args>
auto construct(tag<T>, Args&&...args) -> construction_result<T>
{
    auto x = T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    if (auto result = x.init())
    {
        return std::move(result).value();
    }
    else
    {
        return std::move(x);
    }
}

class A 
{
public:
    A() noexcept { std::cout << "speculative construction" << std::endl; }
    std::optional<construction_error> init() noexcept { 
        if (rand() < RAND_MAX / 2)
        {
            return construction_error("failed to construct an A");
        }
        else
        {
            // complete the construction
            return {};
        }
    }

    int foo();
    void bar();

};

int A::foo()
{
    std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
    // logic here
    return 10;
}

void A::bar()
{
    std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
    // logic here
}

void do_thing(A a, A b, A c)
{
    a.foo();
    b.foo();
    c.foo();
    a.bar();
    b.bar();
    c.bar();
}

template<class T>
void maybe_report_failure(const T&)
{
}

void maybe_report_failure(construction_error const& cf)
{
    std::cout << "construction failure: " << cf.message() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i)
    {
        auto maybe_a_1 = construct(tag<A>());
        auto maybe_a_2 = construct(tag<A>());
        auto maybe_a_3 = construct(tag<A>());

        auto action = [](auto&&...as)
        {
            constexpr bool good = (std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(as)>, A> && ...);
            if constexpr (good)
            {
                do_thing(std::move(as)...);
            }
            else
            {
                (maybe_report_failure(as), ...);
            }
        };
        std::visit(action, 
            std::move(maybe_a_1), 
            std::move(maybe_a_2), 
            std::move(maybe_a_3));
    }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/397427a89afa728a

Answer (score 0):

this should work for both void, default constructible+movable's, and reference types ( not tested :) ):

```
#define CHECK_INITIALIZED_WITH_RETURN(R)                                                 \
if ( !m_is_initialized )                                                   \
{                                                                          \
    LOG_E( m_channel, "%s object not initialized.", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ ); \
    assert( false );                                                       \
    static std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<R,void>,int,std::decay_t<R>> some_default{}; \
    return R(some_default);  \
}
```

where R can be void,T,T&,... ( assuming that the default constructed static has no nasty side effects and it's used in a 'sane' way ... )